# Is modified build-in JavaScript class change Hidden Class Pointer once or every time in V8?

Tags: javascript, v8

I have a code which draws triangle using Path2D object:

```
var path = new Path2D();
    path.moveTo(elem[i], elem[i+1]);
    path.lineTo(elem[i+2], elem[i+3]);
    path.lineTo(elem2[i], elem2[i+1]);
    path.lineTo(elem[i], elem[i+1]);
    path.closePath();
```

But I'm also adding new properties to this object like that:

```
path.topLine = elem;
path.bottomLine = elem2;
```

Then I modify Hidden Class Pointer. And here comes my question: 
**I have many of objects like this above - will they have the same hidden class or it will create new one for every object?**

Should I create some kind of "constructor" first?

For example like that:

```
var path = function(elem, elem2, i){
    this.prototype = new Path2D;
    this.topLine = elem;
    this.bottomLine = elem2;
    this.i = i;
}
```

And then:

```
var path1 = path(someArrayOrObject,someObjectOrArray, someInteger);
```

Comment: If you add the same properties in the same order to all of them, they will have the same hidden class. Still, subclassing `Path2D` might be a good idea, but not like you have shown.

Comment: Yes, this is always the same properties in the same order. So how is it better to subclass?

Comment: Just use one that works :-) The snippet you posted is a syntax error, but you'll find many correct examples on the web

Comment: You should not make assumptions  on stuff like this. If you worry about performance you should measure.

Comment: Okey, I fixed syntax error, but that is not a point. Also we don't really discuss performance here but actual way of working in V8 - so anyway - I got my answer.